# how to pass parameter while including file in jsp using tag

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

i have one jsp page(addStep1.jsp) where i have lot of input fields and drop downs to get values from user.

among all the dropdowns i want to get value from one of the drop down whose id is *svoAffectedSoftware*.

```html
<select id="svoAffectedSoftware" name="svoAffectedSoftware" class="form-control" >
```

Now, on the same page i want to include other jsp file for which i have uses below code (i have uses two approach to solve this but in both the cases i am not getting the desire output. the problem in first approach is i am not getting any error but my page doesn't comes up not even my addStep1.jsp where i have included this code and in the second approach it saying:: The method $(String) is undefined for the type 
__2F_ssappmgr_2F_webapps_2F_sam_2F_apps_2F_itapp_2F_ticket_2F_addStep1_2E_jsp. )

approach 1

```
<%@ include file="ticketResolutionChatBot.jsp?svoAffectedSoftware="svoAffectedSoftware %>
```

or

approach 2

```
<jsp:include page="ticketResolutionChatBot.jsp" >
  <jsp:param name="svoAffectedSoftware" value="<%= $("#svoTicketState").val() %>"/>
</jsp:include>
```

can anyone tell me how do i pass parameter in the correct way also how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want dynamically include one jsp page to another based on the svoAffectedSoftware select value? I just want to clarify your question for myself.

Comment: yes @DmitriiCheremisin

Comment: Is not normal for you to use javascript instead of jsp tags ? It is impossible to do your job with include directive, because it is compiled in servlet before runtime. The same for jsp:include el directive, it will dynamically load page to include, but after page is rendered it will not help.

Comment: thanks @DmitriiCheremisin for your reply. actually i want to include ticketResolutionChatBot.jsp into addStep1.jsp(main page) with the parameter of svoAffectedSoftware. so can you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have uses change() and ajax function here.

```js
$('#svoAffectedSoftware').change(function() { 
       
        var form_data = {
        svoAffectedSoftware: $("#svoAffectedSoftware").val()
                         };
        
       $.ajax({
                       type: "GET",
                       cache: false,
                       url: "getNewPage.jsp",
                       data: form_data,
                       success: function(data){
                        $("#contentDiv").html(data);
                       }
                   });
              });
```

where, url: "getNewPage.jsp"--> redirecting page,
var form_data = {svoAffectedSoftware: $("#svoAffectedSoftware").val()}; --> takes value for the new page which i was asking through parameter,
success: function(data){$("#messageDiv").html(data);} --> include the content of the resultant page into original page (addStep1.jsp) in the specified div.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use javascript for this purpose. With jQuery it is very easy to achieve your goal.

1. Include jQuery library in your jsp page

Example is here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

And here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_lib_microsoft

Don't forget to use all your jquery code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your code for the page
});
```

2. use my example for you from fiddle

   https://jsfiddle.net/u0frjksd/3/

This function subscribes to your select value and loads content page, based on the selection:

```
$(".form-control").on('change', function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
   $('.content').load(value);
});
```

Instead of first value you can provide your own value, I mean your href(in value) to the jsp page you want to  include.

Your jsp page will be loaded to the div .

Comment: Thaks a lot @Dmitrii Cheremisin for your suggestion.